# Is this pattern special expression: "/d$/"...?

Tags: ruby, regex

I met below pattern while i study regular-expression on Ruby.

First, i let you a file for replying.

**test.txt**

```
second
third
not me
```

And this is main file.

**regular_expression_test.rb**

```
File.open("test.txt").grep(/d$/) do |line|
  print line
end
```

Output:

```
second
third
```

Why this example result like Output...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **$** simply marks the end of line. What the special expression **d$** says to the Ruby interpreter is "*Go ahead and match all lines which have a **d** at the end*". In your output, both words have **d** at the end. So they are getting matched and being returned.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're using: `/d$/`, searches test.txt and matches lines ending in `d`.

It outputs the results(matches).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because that regular expresion search all lines that finish on letter d
at the end of line.

**UPDATE:**

The true meaning is "all d\n(s)" or all lines that are finished by d.

If you want to learn or just create a regex I would recommend to you try rubular

http://rubular.com/r/FFl26kHCNO

Comment: Technically, `$` doesn't mean _that_ :)

Comment: The true meaning is "all d\n(s)" or all lines that are fhisished by d